# Feed vkontakte

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как мне использовать(с помощью чего) данные полученные через http://vkontakte.ru/feed2.php 
P.S. Можно ли для этого использовать `JSON`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это json. Используйте [jquery/$.getjson](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_JSON-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Answer (score 0):

Так это и есть JSON. Как проверить? Легко - взять и проверить.